# Making block elements of ul nav automatically fill the whole width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have this menu:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/fcc39c339322a56190bda0755be13444.png))</sub>

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3, the `.container` class. What I am trying to do is, making the elements width scale automatically according to the amount of the elements in the ul + the width of the container.

I have attempted to do this, but this doesn't work:

```
@media (min-width: 428px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .container > #vote > #vote-list {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #vote-list li {
        width: auto;
        float: left;
        display: table-cell;
        margin-left: 1px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

As you see I am firstly accessing `#vote` using `.container` because `#vote` is child of `.container`. `#vote` is basically the dark area you see that the nav is contained in. `#vote-list` is child of `#vote`.

```
#vote {
    background-color: #161616;
    min-height: 560px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have tried changing the child selectors to direct access, but it is giving me the same results.

The html:

```
<body class="container">
    <section id="vote">
        <ul id="vote-list">
            <li>MyNav</li>
            <li>MyNav</li>
            <li>MyNav</li>
            <li>MyNav</li>
            <li>MyNav</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
```

What did I do wrong? Let me know if you need more information

Comment: Are you trying to scale the width of .container to match the navigation or do you want to justify the navigation, so that every item has the same width?

Comment: Every item will have the same width, so it will fit the container, yes (second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```css
#vote-list {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  display: table; /* add this */
}

#vote-list li {
  /* remove float:left; */
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="vote">
  <ul id="vote-list">
    <li>MyNav</li>
    <li>MyNav</li>
    <li>MyNav</li>
    <li>MyNav</li>
    <li>MyNav</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```